# Changing nested attribute with model.set in Backbone

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-model

I'm trying to do what I hope is a simple thing -- doing a model.set only on a sub attribute of the object.

Right now, I have a model that looks like this:

```
{
            "attr1" : true,
            "attr2" : this.model.get("username"),
            "attr3" : $('#tenant_select').val(),
            "attr_array": [
                {
                    "id": "sub_1",
                    "state": "active"
                },
                {
                    "id": "sub_22",
                    "state": "not_active"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I want to be able to grab reach into myMode.attr_array.state and change the value. However, using .set I've only been able to change attributes on the first level, i.e. attr_array.

Is there an way to do this using model.set?

Comment: I bet if you just `.get()` the value of "attr_array" and modify the array contents, that'd work.

Comment: That works, but the issue is that I want to maintain the order of everything inside and right now my solution re-orders consistently

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it (I'm wondering why you didn't manage to do it). But you have to be careful:

```
var array = this.get('attr_array');
array[1].state = 'active';
this.set('attr_array', array);
```

What's the problem here? Your model holds a reference of the object. Therefore the last line is useless, it won't change anything at all. It's simply equivalent to:

```
this.get('attr_array')[1].state = 'active';
```

And you lose any internal stuff Backbone does when you use set.
So what to do? Clone your object:

```
var array = _.clone(this.get('attr_array'));
array[1].state = 'active';
this.set('attr_array', array); // will trigger 'change' and 'change:attr_array' events
```

Comment: Ahh, the cloning did the trick. I had a fix working like the first one you mentioned, but the last one is perfect! Thanks again!